# How many times has Ash enrolled in Pokemon School?

Tags: pokemon

Throughout all the Pokemon TV series and movies, and anything else from the same canon/relevancy, what is the sum total of ashs enrollments in any kind of formal training regarding pokemon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the new-ish *Sun & Moon* series Ash enrolls in [Pokémon School](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_School), to my knowledge this is the only time he formally enrols into any school or long-term training program.

[image: Pokemon School]

Other appearances of formal education in the anime include:

- The [Pokémon Trainers' School](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Trainers%27_School) where Ash gives a guest lecture
- [Pokémon Ninja School](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Ninja_School) where he goes to learn Jujutsu (which doesn't really directly apply to Pokémon)
- [Pokémon Tech](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Tech) where Jessie and James went to school
- The [Pokémon Summer Academy](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Summer_Academy) where Ash enrols in the Diamond & Pearl era. I'd count it, but it's more of a summer camp / summer school thing that only lasts a week (or 4 episodes).

[image]